# Add comma as a delimiter but not between State and ZIP Code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have `[Address]`, `[City]`, `[State]`, `[Zip]` in an array, but any one or more of these may be empty.

I would like to display them on the page with a comma between each key-value pair, but if both State and ZIP are present, they should not get a comma in between!

This is what I have so far:

```
    var student_address_array = [Address, City, State, Zip]; //Put variables into array
    var student_address_array_cleaned = student_address_array.filter(function(v){return v!==''}); //Remove empty array items
    var student_address = student_address_array_cleaned.join(', '); // Convert array to string with ', ' as the delimiter
```

But this puts a comma before ZIP code...

Is the only answer RegEx of some sort?

Comment: How would you know if state and zip are present when there is no identification at to what is what.

Comment: Oh wow. I just need to have the keys present. of course...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concatenate `State` and `Zip` in to the same element of the array and then join the array by comma:

```
var student_address_array = [student_info.Address1, student_info.City, (student_info.State + ' ' + student_info.Zip).trim()];
var student_address = student_address_array.join(', ');
```

```js
var student_info = {
  Address1: 'address1',
  City: 'city',
  State: 'CA',
  Zip: '90210'
};

var student_address_array = [student_info.Address1, student_info.City, (student_info.State + ' ' + student_info.Zip).trim()];
var student_address = student_address_array.join(', ');

console.log(student_address);
```

Comment: Ah that's brilliant. And the trim at the end to account for the scenario that one of State or ZIP are missing!

Comment: That's it exactly :)

Comment: This will however fail if values are `null` or `undefined`. Might not be a problem though.

Comment: Does `join()` ignore empty elements in the array? I feel like I still need to filter for them before the join, in case one of the elements are empty.

Comment: No, `join()` won't ignore empty values, so you would still need the filter if `Address1` or `City` are allowed to be empty.